# Spring datasource connection to MS SQL Server named instance

Tags: java, sql-server, spring, jtds

I am getting an error when trying to create a datasource connection to MS SQL server named instance using JTDS driver within my Spring Config.

My spring datasource configuration is :

```
<bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="${db.driver}" />
    <property name="url" value="${db.jdbcurl}" />
    <property name="username" value="${db.username}" />
    <property name="password" value="${db.password}" />
</bean>
```

and db.properties is :

```
db.driver=net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver
db.jdbcurl=jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://SQL_SERVER_HOSTNAME/TEST2012:1433/TESTDB;
db.username=DB_UserName
db.password=DB_Password
```

In above properties file **TEST2012** is an instance of SQL server and **TESTDB** is database on named instance.

It's throwing below exception :

```
ERROR: HHH000319: Could not get database metadata
java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://SQL_SERVER_HOSTNAME/TEST2012:1433/TESTDB
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource.getConnectionFromDriverManager(DriverManagerDataSource.java:153)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource.getConnectionFromDriver(DriverManagerDataSource.java:144)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.AbstractDriverBasedDataSource.getConnectionFromDriver(AbstractDriverBasedDataSource.java:155)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.AbstractDriverBasedDataSource.getConnection(AbstractDriverBasedDataSource.java:120)
```

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: What jar for driver do you use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

jTDS requires to specify the named instance via a [property](http://jtds.sourceforge.net/faq.html):

```
jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://SQL_SERVER_HOSTNAME:1433/TESTDB?instance=TEST2012
```